# NSTintConfiguration for NSOutlineView not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsoutlineview

I am trying to change the tint color of some of my items in my `NSOutlineView`. The delegate method is being called, however the color does not change. Here is what I do:

```
@available(OSX 11.0, *)
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, tintConfigurationForItem item: Any) -> NSTintConfiguration? {
    return NSTintConfiguration(fixedColor: NSColor.systemYellow)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this question, I've found the answer. Make sure the `imageView` outlet of the `NSTableCellView` is connected to the to the `NSImageView` that is your icon. Otherwise the `NSOutlineView` does not know what image to colorise. It is connected by default, but I did remove the connection since I did not need it for anything else.

Comment: Oh thanks Daniel, after one year you've already forgotten about that. 